# windows phone 8.1 tone generator function

Tags: frequency, windows-phone-8.1

I am currently starting to write an app for windows phone 8.1 platform and one of the tasks involves generating a tone with specific frequency. I know the the function for a console application in C# which is Console.Beep(100,900); where 100 is the frequency and 900 is the duration of the beep.
I need to do the exact same thing for windows phone 8.1 .